# executing current line then search for next and execute

Tags: vim

hi i have a file with this content

```
 mysql -uroot -ppass sas -e 'SHOW CREATE PROCEDURE add_customer\G'
 mysql -uroot -ppass sas -e 'SHOW CREATE PROCEDURE add_order\G'
 mysql -uroot -ppass sas -e 'SHOW CREATE PROCEDURE add_to_cart\G'
 mysql -uroot -ppass sas -e 'SHOW CREATE PROCEDURE add_to_wish_list\G'
 mysql -uroot -ppass sas -e 'SHOW CREATE PROCEDURE add_transaction\G'
 mysql -uroot -ppass sas -e 'SHOW CREATE PROCEDURE clear_cart\G'
 mysql -uroot -ppass sas -e 'SHOW CREATE PROCEDURE get_order_contents\G'
 mysql -uroot -ppass sas -e 'SHOW CREATE PROCEDURE get_shopping_cart_contents\G'
 mysql -uroot -ppass sas -e 'SHOW CREATE PROCEDURE get_wish_list_contents\G'
 mysql -uroot -ppass sas -e 'SHOW CREATE PROCEDURE receipt_retrieve\G'
 mysql -uroot -ppass sas -e 'SHOW CREATE PROCEDURE remove_from_cart\G'
 mysql -uroot -ppass sas -e 'SHOW CREATE PROCEDURE remove_from_wish_list\G'
 mysql -uroot -ppass sas -e 'SHOW CREATE PROCEDURE select_categories\G'
 mysql -uroot -ppass sas -e 'SHOW CREATE PROCEDURE select_products\G'
 mysql -uroot -ppass sas -e 'SHOW CREATE PROCEDURE select_sale_items\G'
 mysql -uroot -ppass sas -e 'SHOW CREATE PROCEDURE update_cart\G'
 mysql -uroot -ppass sas -e 'SHOW CREATE PROCEDURE update_wish_list\G'
```

I want to use a function to execute each line and replace with the command output, then search for the next line that begins with "mysql" and execute that line.. until the end of the file.

here is my function

```
r !mysql -uroot -ppass sas -e 'SELECT name FROM mysql.proc;'
    normal! gg /name<CR>n
    normal! dd
    %normal! I mysql -uroot -ppass sas -e 'SHOW CREATE PROCEDURE 
    normal! ggdd0 
    %normal A\G'
    normal! gg0
    normal! G
    let lastline = line(".")
    echom lastline 
    normal! gg0
"here is where i want to start
    .!sh
**"back to normal to search**
    normal! /mysql<CR> n 
**"when found execute the line**
    %normal !!sh
    ".!sh
endfunction
```

This works for the first line but i cant figure out how to do the whole range of lines. I know im close..

Comment: It will allow me to use 1,18!sh but not 1,.lastline.!sh am i doing this correctly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure if you really need a function for it.

**way 1**

can you simply do :

```
:%!sh
```

to execute whole buffer once?

**way 2**

For example, if you have some line in your buffer not starting with `mysql`, and you don't want to execute them, you could do:

```
:g/^mysql/.!sh
```

**way 3**

if you really want to do it one by one, like you described in your question, execute and move to next `mysql`, execute, you could do it as macro:

```
/^mysql<cr>          "search the pattern
gg                   "cursor back to top
qq                   "start recording to q
!!sh<cr>             "run first line as shell command, take output back
n                    "next command line (with pattern)
q                    "stop recording
```

then

```
500@q
```

if you have 500 lines to be executed.

Comment: This is what ended up working for me
function! Myproc()
r !mysql -uroot -ppass sas -e 'SELECT name FROM mysql.proc;'
    normal! gg /name<CR>n
    normal! dd
    %normal! I mysql -uroot -ppass sas -e 'SHOW CREATE PROCEDURE 
    normal! ggdd0 
    %normal A\G'
    normal! gg0
    normal! G
    let lastline = line(".")
    exec '1,'.lastline.'!sh'
endfunction

It worked perfect